# Communication method for data exchange between a server and several clients for 10+ years

Tags: c++, ssh, openssl, protocols

We're running [an experiment](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5524) which will involve collecting data from multiple stations around the world. Each station will be providing [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) files with magnetic field measurements in a rate of 1 kHz and some auxiliary data *in real time*. The latency is going to be a few minutes.

I'm assigned to design this program (in C++, with clients/server model, with server being in linux and clients being cross-platform), and apparently I'll be designing this from scratch. My first concern is not to really do everything from scratch because this will be more error prone and pure wrong, so my question here is: What information/file transfer protocols/libraries should I use so that

1. The program can live for 10+ years with minimal maintenance
2. I can have very good support from the community for when I need help.

Since we need something relatively secure, my first thought was [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) (the only cross platform opensource library available out there for ssh), but then after discussing with some pros there I realized that the support there isn't so wonderful because only a few people work with libssh. The pros there hesitated in suggesting OpenSSL, but with OpenSSL I'll have to write my own authentication (apparently, I'm not an expert and that's why I'm asking).

What would you suggest? Please share your vision to whether I should go for OpenSSL, libssh, or something else.

PS: Please, if you're going to start off by saying this question is off-topic, move on and ignore it. Consider being helpful rather than critical.

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: So basically you're saying you should be able to ignore the rules and ask off-topic questions with impunity - why?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't know if this question is off-topic, but I'm not ready for hard-*** people wasting my time and I'm really sick of it. I need help and need experts to look at my problem and here's the place where I can find them.

Comment: You clearly knew your question was off-topic otherwise why mention it? For reference, the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) explains what type of questions you can ask here. Currently your question falls under _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it_

Comment: @JonathanPotter You're judging the situation and assuming that I haven't done anything for it and the problem with your kind. There's some judgement to be done to decide whether a question violates the rules, and your kind prefers negative judgement as they enjoy it for some reason I don't and probably will never understand! So not untll a 100 people say this question is off-topic, I'll be here hoping for someone to ask for more details and help.

Comment: Actually it will only take 3 more :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for negatively contributing to my problem.

Comment: As someone doing research you should know how to ... Research ... There are papers in computer science too

Comment: @Otomo Once you see a computer scientist reading particle physics papers, then ask a particle physicist to read computer science papers. Please be reasonable!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist If that is your attitude it would be better to hire someone who knows how to do it.

Comment: @Otomo Asking to read primary papers just to write a program is absolutely unreasonable. I wrote hundreds of programs by reading books and websites. Papers usually offer very specialized and targeted information that is absolutely not helpful for someone looking for a practical solution for a standard problem like this one. Do I really have to teach you the difference between primary sources and tertiary sources like books? Your attitude is like someone asking a physicist "what is an electron", and the physicist responding "go read the 2012 paper on the Higgs boson to get the answer"...Really?

Answer (score 2):

I think that OpenSSL might be a good choice.
No you do not have to "write you own authentication" - you just need to generate certificates and keys and put them in the right places - that is all.
I would suggest to look at the examples in `<openssl-source-dir>/demos` and `<openssl-source-dir>/apps` to get you started. Reading a book about OpenSSL would also be a good idea - for many other reasons (sometimes not directly related with SSL/TLS).

I hope that helps.